# python json(how to read mulpite id in comple

Tags: python

I have json file i what to read all the values

```
 data=""" {"employees":[
        {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
        {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
        {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
    ]} 
     {
         "maps":[
                 {"id":"apple","iscategorical":"0"},
                 {"id":"ball","iscategorical":"0"}
                ],

        "mask":{"id1":"aaaaa"},
        "mask":{"id1":"bbb"},
        "mask":{"id1":"cccccc"},

        "om_points":"value",
        "parameters":
                 {"id":"valore"}
        }"""
        out = json.loads(data)
```

how to get all values

1. firstname
2. lastname
3. mask.id1
4. map.id

output:

```
[(firstname_vaues,lastname_values,mask.id1,map.id)
         (firstname_vaues,lastname_values,mask.id1,map.id) ......]
```

please help me

Comment: I suggest you read the [``json``](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) documentation, and try to adopt one of the examples to your case. If you run into specific difficulties, ask again.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, there are  two json objects in your data string. So you cannot use json.loads(data). You can seperate them by a charcter like ";" . Then split the string and use json.loads on each of them.Use following code.

```
import json
data=""" {
"employees": [{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
}, {
    "firstName": "Anna",
    "lastName": "Smith"
}, {
    "firstName": "Peter",
    "lastName": "Jones"
}]
};{
"maps": [{
    "id": "apple",
    "iscategorical": "0"
}, {
    "id": "ball",
    "iscategorical": "0"
}],

"mask": {
    "id1": "aaaaa"
},
"mask": {
    "id1": "bbb"
},
"mask": {
    "id1": "cccccc"
},

"om_points": "value",
"parameters": {
    "id": "valore"
}
}"""

splitdata = data.split(';')

datatop = json.loads(splitdata[0])
databottom = json.loads(splitdata[1])
```

Then you can access required fields as follows

```
print(datatop['employees'][0]['firstName'])
print(datatop['employees'][0]['lastName'])
print(databottom['mask']['id1'])
print(databottom['maps'][0]['id'])
```